# DRF: Seperate fields for each CRUD operation on the same Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that looks like this

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('A', 'B')   
        # 'C' is mandatory to create the object but dont include it on GET

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # validated_data contains C ...
        instance = MyModel(**validated_data)
        print instance.__dict__  # C is None !?!?!
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

- When I return the resources, following a GET request, I want only **'A' and 'B'** for each row (object)
- When I create the resource, following a POST request, I have to include a mandatory third attribute **'C'**

The view does it's job correctly and passes **C** inside `validated_data`, but when I create the `MyModel` it ends up without C value as shown above.

If **I add 'C' in `fields` tuple** then everything works correctly ...

Is there a sensible way to distinguish between the two cases? Writing mutliple serializers (so that each one defines different fields) seems too ugly to me.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you can use DRF extra_kwargs in Meta as shown in this one http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ramiel was right. I had missed that property in extra_kwargs. Finally the exact solution was:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('A', 'B', 'C')
        extra_kwargs = {'C': {'write_only': True}}
```

If I don't include 'C' at `fields` it's not passed in `validated_data`.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('A', 'B', 'C')
        extra_kwargs = {'C': {'write_only': True}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ramiel. That was what I needed. I also needed to include id at `fields` as well in order to exist in `validated_data`. For some reason the previous behavior of validated_data containing anything was not any more the case when I removed all .pyc files. I posted the final exact answer below